# King associated with the number four

Tags: identification, kingdom

Long back, in a children's magazine, I had read a trivia about a certain king, whose life had multiple associations with the number four. I cannot recollect what the associations were exactly, but some examples of how the associations were worded: he was the fourth emperor with his title, he was born and dead on the fourth of a month, he was one of four siblings, he had four children, etc.

I am unable to search for this trivia online. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

I guess he could be anyone, but one who more or less fits is [Edward IV of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_IV_of_England) – he was one of four brothers who survived into adulthood, was the fourth king by the name Edward, had four sons (including an illegitimate one), and his reign began on March 4, 1461. Maybe there's more trivia around about him matching the number 4.

Comment: He was also the 4th Duke of York. He was both born and died in April, the fourth month. However, like most of these numerical "associations", there's always an element of cherry-picking required to make it all work. After all, he was the second son (of eight) of Richard, the 3rd Duke of York, He was also the 7th Earl of March, 5th Earl of Cambridge and 9th Earl of Ulster. He had 10 children (and possibly another 5 illegitimate ones). He was born on the 28th and died on the 9th of the month. Of his four sons, only two survived into adulthood.

Comment: He died at the age of forty; his height was an impressive 6' 4''.

Comment: Edward's 3 brother's did not all live until adulthood. His brother Edmund Earl of Rutland was born 17 May 1443 and died 30 December 1460, at the Battle of Wakefield, aged 17 years, 7 months, and 13 days. He was either killed fighting during the battle or murdered after the battle.